# Запись из List<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, list

Есть ли возможность в `WPF` записать в `TextBlock` элемент из `List<string>`?

Comment: Есть, получите нужный вам элемент из списка и запишите его в `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var strings = new List<string>()
        {
            "Hello", "World"
        };
        textblock1.Text = strings[0];
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот. Изменяем свойство `TextBlock` `Text` на то которое нам нужно. В данном случае на один из элементов списка, к которому мы обращаемся по индексу

Так же можно соединять строки:

```
 var strings = new List<string>()
        {
            "Hello", "World"
        };
        textblock1.Text = strings[0] + strings[1];
```

И проводить другие манипуляции как и с обычными строками. Подробнее о строках [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/)

**SeeSharp**